# Is there a right way to implement distributed caching (resistent to concurrent writing, netsplits, etc)?

Tags: caching, redis, memcached, distributed-computing, distributed-system

Lets say we have a database (PostgreSQL). Some requests are too expensive or slow, so we decided to cache some data, say, in Memcached. At first everything seems to be OK, but in fact there is a number of corner cases:

- Some Memcached servers could be unavailable (server is down, netsplits)
- Writes by one key can occur concurrently by 2+ backends
- Memcached server was added/removed, some backends are already aware of this, some are not
- etc

Is there some well known solution to avoid inconsistency between caches and database under these circumstances? I can think of a few really simple solutions, but they lead to stale reads.

Comment: Write operations which bypass the cache will *always* lead to stale reads. So the question is, how can you write to the DB and invalidate the cached state *at the exact same time* - at least as seen from the cache's clients. - Simple answer: Synchronize write accesses with cache invalidation and client reads, so that clients can only read (from cache) before the write operation or after the cache invalidation but not in between. OTOH, stale reads may be tolerable if they're just temporary for some milliseconds.

Comment: Hanno, this is simplest problem possible and solution is quite obvious - first invalidate cache, then write. Other problems described above are far more complicated.

Comment: Won't work. What happens if someone does a read after the cache is invalidated but before the write completed? - The cache reloads the old state which will be stale almost instantly.

Comment: Hanno, you are right. This is exactly what CAS is for.